# Is there a possible way to script which apps are the specified ones to run using "Run only specified applications" in a Group Policy?

Tags: command-line, powershell, script, group-policy

I wanna be able to script which applications I want my group to be able to run via the cmd :

[image: Here's what the rule looks like]

[image: Here are the possible options]

[image: The apps the group can run]

Is there a way to script this to execute via powershell or CMD on boot? Has anyone ever done it?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: It is possible, but it will come with a huge drawback. The only way you can make this possible is by using the local group policy. That way, you can use a powershell script and set this locally. The drawback is, that one can then simply use gpedit.msc locally to change the list, undoing your changes.

Comment: It would be easier to use multiple group policies and predefine the different options, and set permissions to give certain users gp1 and other users gp2 etc...

Comment: Actually, I'm trying to automate this via EC2s on AWS. I'd like to automatically create on-demand Windows instances with users with exclusive access to specific applications.
Hence, by transforming the application to run into a parameter, we can make it more dynamic. However, is it feasible? I have no idea lol

Comment: You should be looking at a kiosk mode setup for this. Kiosk mode allows the administrator to set the application(s) that can run in a limited Windows environment.

Comment: kiosk mode setup doesn't apply to Window Server 2019 unfortunately, I've been looking it up for the past hour.

Comment: from the MS applocker/SRP page ... >>> `AppLocker policies can be updated by using the Local Security Policy snap-in (if the policies are created locally), or the GPMC, or the Windows PowerShell AppLocker cmdlets.`

Answer (score 0):

No need to script this, Use the built-in enterprise-ready solution for such use cases.

[Software Restriction Policies Technical Overview ...](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/software-restriction-policies/software-restriction-policies-technical-overview#:%7E:text=Table%201%20%20%20%20Application%20control%20function,exceptions%20whic%20...%20%203%20more%20rows%20)

[Software Restriction Policies | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/software-restriction-policies/software-restriction-policies)

[Administer Software Restriction Policies | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/software-restriction-policies/administer-software-restriction-policies)

[Work with Software Restriction Policies Rules | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/software-restriction-policies/work-with-software-restriction-policies-rules)

[Use Software Restriction Policies and AppLocker policies ...](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-application-control/applocker/using-software-restriction-policies-and-applocker-policies)

[SRP Policy Settings images](https://www.bing.com/images/search?q=windows%20software%20restriction%20policy&form=HDRSC2&first=1&scenario=ImageBasicHover)

[Youtube Videos - software restriction policy](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=software%20restriction%20policy)